# Test fails when using LinkContainer from react-router-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-bootstrap

So I am making a ReactJS app which includes reactstrap, react-router and react-router-bootstrap. The problem is that when I test components which contain LinkContainer, the following error occurs, making my unit tests fail:

> console.error node_modules\prop-types\checkPropTypes.js:19
>         Warning: Failed context type: The context `router` is marked as required in `LinkContainer`, but its value is `undefined`.
>             in LinkContainer (at Header.js:27)

Could anyone please help me out? This is the code, in header.js for example:

```
import { LinkContainer } from "react-router-bootstrap";
import { ROUTE_POKEDEX } from "../../constants/constants";

export default class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false
    };
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container fluid className="header">
        <Navbar expand="md">
          <LinkContainer to={ROUTE_POKEDEX}>
            <NavbarBrand>Pokédex</NavbarBrand>
          </LinkContainer>
          <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
        </Navbar>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

test.js

```
import Header from "./Header";

it("renders without crashing", () => {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  ReactDOM.render(<Header />, div);
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
});

it("has valid snapshot", () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(<Header />).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `LinkContainer` component needs to be wrapped by `Router`, hence the error in your unit tests (Router doesn't get called when the individual component is being rendered in your test).  Possible solution is using `<MemoryRouter>`.
From the docs:

> Starting at specific routes
>
> supports the initialEntries and initialIndex props, so
>   you can boot up an app (or any smaller part of an app) at a specific
>   location.

See: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/guides/testing/starting-at-specific-routes

Possible solution in the op's test case scenario would be to do something like this in the unit test when rendering the component (untested):

`ReactDOM.render(<MemoryRouter><Header /></MemoryRouter>, div);`